# Golang Broken Characters When Writing Files

Tags: string, go

I run this code

```
cmd := exec.Command(sArg[0], sArg[1:]...)
d, err := cmd.Output()
if len(arg) == 0 {
    return err
}
file.WriteString(string(d))
```

After running it, the string is printed well in the debugging console, but the character is broken in the file.

Original Output

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile
    DisableNotifications    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EnableFirewall    REG_DWORD    0x1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\Logging
```

Broken Output in File

[image]

How can characters be correctly written to a file?

Comment: What are the values of the first ~16 bytes of `d`? Does it look like ascii or unicode?

Comment: @byxor ~16 bytes is []uint8{13, 10, 72, 75, 69, 89, 75, 76, 79, 67, 65, 76, 95, 77, 65, 67, 72}. transfer hex...{0d, 0a, 48, 4b, 45, 59, 4b, 4c, 4f, 43, 41, 4c, 5f, 4d, 61 43, 48}

Comment: The bytes look fine and translate to `\r\nHKEYKLOCAL_MACH`... so there should be no reason for your results.

Comment: How do you create `file` ?

Comment: Tip: There's a [file.Write](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) function, which accepts `[]byte` as a parameter. This saves you from converting it to a string first.

Comment: @KevinBusse Use os.Create

Comment: @byxor i tried it but same result.

Comment: @KevinBusse Before this code, we also wrote the output from other commands to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take `0d, 0a, 48, 4b, 45, 59, 4b, 4c, 4f, 43, 41, 4c, 5f, 4d, 61 43, 48` and assume it's encoded using [UTF-16-LE](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) this will be displayed as ਍䭈奅䱋䍏䱁䵟䍡 which looks about the same as the first section of your screenshot. As such it appears to me that your program is saving the data correctly but the application you are using to view the file is incorrectly interpreting it as UTF-16-LE encoded.

It is possible that this is due to whatever you wrote to the file previously (you mention that this data is being appended to data written earlier). If the first two bytes are FF, FE this can be taken as a signal that the file is [UTF-16-LE](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) encoded but not all editors will recognise this).

If you open the file in a hex editor I expect that you will see the data as expected (i.e. `0d, 0a, 48,`...).

Comment: Thanks, So I found this problem.
Here are some findings of the problem. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086434/golang-how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string)
I will appreciate it if you see it and answer the question.